# Couldn't read the response consistently from API - HTTP

Tags: c, http, pic

I'm working on communication protocol called HTTP in a PIC microcontroller interface M95 GSM module. I'm trying HTTP POST method. I've successfully posted and read the response. The problem is I can't read the response consistently from Api. I've written the code that if I can't read the response after post the payload I'm again to post the same payload for 5 times to read the response. The image I've attached you can see after posted one payload, I got "Got created response", but you see I didn't read the response after posted for 5 times.

Thanks
[image]

part of a post and read code:

```
        bool SendAtCommand_Response(char *command, char *response,int time);
....
        SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPPOST=165,25,10\r","CONNECT",2000);
        /*Stream forming*/
       sprintf(stream_data,"Speed=0&Imei_no=%s&Battery_voltage=%f&Fuel_voltage=%f&Latitude=%f&Longitude=%f&Ignition=%s&Gps_valid=%s&Utc_Time=%s",imei_no(),bat_vol(),fuel_vol(),gps_lat(),gps_long(),ignition_status(),gps_va(),gps_utc());
       printf("Length of stream:=%d\n",strlen(stream_data)); 
       do
       {
        SendAtCommand_Response(stream_data,"OK",2000);
        printf("%s\n",stream_data);
        Delayms(500);
        clear();
        SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPREAD=30\r","CONNECT",3000);
        if(strstr(gprs_buffer,"CREATED"))
            {
                //uart1str(gprs_buffer);
                uart1str("Got created response\r\n");
                uart1str("\r\n");
                p=5;
            }
        p++;
       }while(p<=4);
        clear();

    }
```

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: @MikeofSST Thanks for the reply. Actually i'm using own REST API.

Comment: what API are you using on the PIC side?

Comment: What is the actual content of the `gprs_buffer` variable after the `AT+QHTTPREAD=30\r` command?

Comment: Im receiving the response and store it in gprs_buffer variable. If i posted successfully i will get the response `CONNECT CREATED`. `CONNECT` response is for QHTTPREAD and `CREATED` is send by API.